# Body has no closing tag. Is it fine?

Tags: wordpress, header

I want to add google analytics code just before the /head and I just realized that the body has no / closing tag anywhere.
Can somebody confirm that this is fine? thank you.

This is the [header.php file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZeqpXilP7pSSAWax9i_HnBln4n4Ysrai)

Comment: You need to read some blogs and documentation how theme files are working in wordpress

Comment: Yes it fine because body tag will close in footer.php in your theme file

Comment: Thank you @BhaveshTaneja

Answer (score 0):

Yes; as [Bhavesh Taneja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9838667/bhavesh-taneja) said, it will work. The  closing tag isn't supposed to be in the header anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the fast answers guys. I just checked the footer php and i have just a closing body tag, since the opening is in header, now i understand. Thank you!
Regards

Answer (score 0):

> No some tags in html + html5 no need to close with end tags it's
>   closed by self
>   like:

a line break `(<br/>)` or the meta tag `(<meta>)`. This means that the following are both acceptable:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

and

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

Some closing tags are optional.

> The minifier removes the closing tags `</head></body></html>` etc. cause they are not needed:

Answer (score -1):

It actually really depends on your use case. If the website you are building is meant to only run in your local environment somewhere, meaning you have a private server within your home network or maybe even a web server installed on your own system, then the structure doesn't really matter, as long as the values are shown the way you want them to. This though, I would call quick and dirt. Actually, very dirty!

If more people than just yourself should see the results of your page, then ofcourse you need `<body>` and `</body>` in your website. And there are more HTML-tags that have to be properly closed after being opened, as otherwise the result would be very random.

Checkout this page for a little introduction on how to build a proper page:

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp